# Class diagram for a recruitment management system

Tags: javascript, orm, uml, class-diagram, system-design

I am building a recruitment management system where the head recruiter can log in and add a new job, then he can assign candidates to that job. Each one of those candidates has their own steps (screening, interviews, tests, etc...) before they get hired.

For example: the candidate with id 3 has 6 steps before he gets hired, while candidate with id 21 has only 2 steps before getting hired.

Note that the same candidate can be assigned to different jobs.
For example: candidate with id 6, applied to job PHP Dev and job Technical Lead.

I am trying to figure out how to design this system but I am stuck at the class diagram:
[image: Class diagram]

Edit: this is a backlog for recruiters only, the recruiter will select the right candidates from the LinkedIn job post and add them to the system.

Comment: Have you considered adding an Application between Candidate and Position?

Comment: @cmolina indeed! It's not fully clear to me, in the narrative if it's a head-hunting firm that decides which candidate in their pool they want to consider for which job,  or if it's a traditional recruitment business where people apply for a job. But regardless of the answer the Application/Assignment is what's missing.

Comment: I have updated my question and added more clarifications about the use case. I am surely looking at the Application/Assignment but I cannot see the necessity of it, what role is it going to play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Clarification

It's not explicit in your narrative, but I understand that the steps depend  on the candidate AND the job. For example candidate 6 could have 3 steps for the PHP position, and 19 steps for the tech lead position.

### Possible solutions

This more complex relationship could be decomposed in a very simple manner using an **intermediary class**:

[image]

An “assignment” would be for one candidate applying to one job and define several different steps.  Conversely,  A position can more than one assignment. Similarly a candidate could be associated with several assignments, and each step corresponds to one assignment.

Another alternative is to use an **association class**:

[image]

There is a slightly different semantic focus in this diagram compared to the previous one: here there is a many to many association, between candidate and position, and the association-class describes more about this association. I think it corresponds more to to your narrative, but the implementation would anyway be very similar to the previous one.

You could also define a **ternary association**, but I would not recommend it here.

### Additional thoughts

The remaining question is: why do steps differ depending on the candidates? From an [ethical point of view](https://www.acm.org/code-of-ethics), wouldn’t this dangerously facilitate discriminations? Moreover, wouldn’t the manual creation of steps be tedious and repetitive?

It seems therefore more desirable, to have some standardized  `Template Steps` defined for the position, and when a candidate is assigned to this position, the template steps would be used to create an initial set of steps for the “assignment”. The admin could remove the unnecessary one, or add new ones, filling at this occasion a `justification` property. I leave you as an exercise the corresponding modelling ;-)

Comment: I appreciate this detailed response, I have added more clarifications about the use case above in the question. The system is a backlog for recruiters only, candidates won't have any role in this so I cannot see the reason of adding the assignment class.

Comment: For your additional thoughts, I understand your concerns but the hiring process can differ from one department to another. For example, hiring customer support is totally different process than hiring a software engineer.